# I want to create a FIFO but it isn't being created

Tags: c, unix

I want to create a simple FIFO using C.  However, the function is returning -1. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    if(mkfifo("test",0666) == -1)
    {
        printf("Something went wrong\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `perror` for more information.

Comment: perror said "operation not permited" any ideia on how to solve that?

Comment: What Unix flavor? I don't see that error code listed for `mkfifo()`. Make sure you call `perror()` immediately after `mkfifo()`, not after `printf()`, since it can (and usually does) change `errno`.

Comment: kinda new to this operating sistems concepts so if by flavor u mean version its ubunto,yeah meanwhile i used perror() before the printf() and it came out "operation not permited"

Comment: I meant Linux vs. BSD vs. MacOS etc, and Debian means Linux. Are you trying to create the FIFO on an ordinary filesystem, or is it something like a USB thumb drive?

Comment: oh ok, linux then... ordinary filesystem

Comment: This [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118671) says that this error can happen if it's a Windows volumn mounted with CIFS. Another site mentioned that it can happen if the filesystem is mounted with the "immutable" option.

Comment: Most likely, you are running the program in a directory where you do not have write permission.  If worst comes to worst, try doing: `cd /tmp; /path/to/your/rpgram` and see whether it works there, or reports a different error.